# How to add a post build step for maven release in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to copy files in a post build step only when maven release gets performed.

Unfortunately, there are no actions (such as a post build step or pre build step) on clicking Perform Maven release link in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Jenkins Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin) which will do for what you are searching. It's an additional Jenkins Plugin for the plugin "Maven Release".

The Release Plugin adds Pre/Post Build Configuration Dialog to the Build Enviroment Configuration Dialog. Can be enabled with checking the checkbox "Release Build configration".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that plugin: [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task).